# Does Key based authentication replace or rather supplement password authentication?

Tags: ssh, passwords, public-key-encryption

Is SSH key based authentication something that happens to replace password authentication or does it supplement password authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several authentication methods can be **allowed**, but only one is usually<sup>1</sup> **used** – for example, if the server offers `gssapi-with-mic, publickey, password` and client chooses `publickey`, then *only* the key will be used for authentication and all other methods will be skipped.

---

<sup>1</sup> In some *very rare* situations, two auth methods will be used for the same connection – for example, when the first connection to Bitvise WinSSHd uses publickey it will additionally ask for the password – but this is an exception to the rule.